# Bootstrap layout - not centered and bad zooming

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap, center

i am now working for several days now on a header for our project. Everything is ok - but the layout not.

In my Layout I have on the left a logo, in the middle a navbar, and on the right Login/Logout/Register links.

My Problem is, that I can't center the navbar as I want, if I try, then it is only for my display resolution ok and e.g. if I zoom in or out, it is going bad.

[This](http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/312_bs/My-Bootstrap-Site-NAVBAR/navbar-examples.html) is also very nice, but I don't know how to do it.

I would be really glad if somebody could help me.

Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
    <body>
  <div class="row">

        <div class="span3">        
                <img src="/resources/img/logos/bb_logotype_blue_110.png" />
        </div>

    <div class="span6">
               <!-- NavBar -->
               <ul id="navbar">
                <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
               </ul>                
    </div>

    <div class="span3"></div>                
                <div id="nav-account" class="nav-collapse pull-right">
                        <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a id="register" href="/register">Register</a></li>
                <li><a id="login" href="/login/form">Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:3em">

    <h1 id="title"></h1>
    ... some stuff ...


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    <style>
    body {
      padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */

    }


    #navbar li
    {
        display: inline;
        border-right: 2px solid black;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16pt;
    }

    #navbar li:last-child
    {
        border-right: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap, if you place elements inside a `<container>` block, they will be automatically centered and resized to fit in the grid layout. Perhaps that is what you are looking for.